# How to force dump on crash-restart?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, crash, minidumps

My application crashes and force-restarts the computer, but no crash dump files are generated with several configurations; how can I get the system to generate a crash file in this case (or anything similar to help debug the problem)?

---

**Details**: the .exe is a video game that randomly freezes for a few secs, with a static noise, and forces Windows to restart. No error message before or after the crash - just a complete loss of control on freeze, then stuff works normally post-restart. No other application (or game) elicits this behavior, including much more demanding ones*. Posted on active forums, no replies - so other users don't seem to experience the same.

*: e.g. more demanding games, or deep neural networks with ~100% GPU, CPU, and RAM utility

---

**System info**:

- **System**: Win-10 OS, ASUS ROG Strix [GL702VSK](https://amzn.to/2TAedUh)
- **RAM**: 24GB DDR4 2.4-MHz
- **CPU**: [i7-7700HQ 2.8 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)

---

**Crash dump configs**: directory `%SystemRoot%\...` ("C:\Windows")

1. Small memory dump (256 KB)
2. Kernel memory dump *(I have sufficient disk space)*
3. Complete memory dump
4. Automatic memory dump

Checkmarked:

- Write an event to the system log
- Automatically restart
- Overwrite any existing file
- Disable automatic deletion of memory dumps when disk space is low
- Time to display list of operating systems (30 secs)

Comment: Uncheck Automatically Restart and see if you can see / save the dump when it freezes next.   Nirsoft Blue Screen View is good for looking at dumps.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for recorded errors.